Topological Hochschild Homology and $p$-adic étale cohomology of $\mathbb{Q}$-schemes
Recent progress in $p$-adic geometry has produced an interesting comparison isomorphism between the crystalline cohomology of a smooth algebra $A$ over a perfect field $k$ in characteristic $p$, and the syntomic cohomology of
certain sheaf, computed using a variant of $\mathrm{THH}$ called negative cyclic homology, denoted $\mathrm{TC}^-(A)$. I avoid making the explicit statement but a reference is BMS2, Theorem 1.10.
Since crystalline cohomology of a scheme compares to the geometric étale cohomology of a smooth lift to characteristic $0$, there seems to be some evidence that a certain variant of $\mathrm{THH}$ "computes" the $p$-adic étale cohomology of certain schemes over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Is there any basis to think that a variant of $\mathrm{THH}$ computes the $p$-adic étale cohomology of certain schemes over $\mathbb{Q}$?

The original $\operatorname{THH}$ is the same as $\operatorname{HH}(-/\mathbb Q)$ for $\mathbb Q$-schemes, basically because $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb S}\mathbb Q\xrightarrow\simeq\mathbb Q$. There are, however, refined $\operatorname{THH}$ and $\operatorname{TC}^-$, based on Efimov's rigidity of motives. This is covered in Scholze's talk and Wagner's slides.
